# Truecrypt 7.0 build

Tags: visual-studio, device-driver, nmake, truecrypt

I'm trying to build [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) 7.0
I have build the driver. But I can't build the Boot Project.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Boot, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Performing Makefile project actions
1>NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0xc0000135'
1>Stop.
```

The Boot Project has a Makefile.

```
MSVC16_ROOT = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC # I set the value by myself.
!ifndef MSVC16_ROOT
!error Environment variable MSVC16_ROOT must point to the installation directory of MS Visual C++ 1.5
!endif
ENVPATH = $(PATH);
CC = "$(MSVC16_ROOT)\bin\cl.exe"
```

Let me know what the problem is.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the requirements I found to get TrueCrypt 7.0 compiled properly :

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 (Professional Edition or compatible)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 1.52 (available from MSDN Subscriber Downloads)
- Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
- Microsoft Windows Driver Kit 7.0.0 (build 7600.16385.0)
- RSA Security Inc. PKCS #11 Cryptographic Token Interface (Cryptoki) 2.20
  header files (available at
  ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-20)
- NASM assembler (2.06 or compatible)
- gzip compressor

As you can see there is a clear distinction between VS 2008 C++ Compiler and Visual C++ 1.52. I think your error comes from the fact that you are trying to compile with the wrong compiler ! Install Visual C++ 1.52 and compile with this one !

Visual C++ 1.52 can be found on MSDN Subscriber downloads.